# Виджет приложения в сообществе ВКонтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Недавно у ВКонтакте появилась возможность ставить виджеты в группы (https://vk.com/dev/apps_widgets).

Я не понял, как сделать свой виджет? Куда нужно вписывать сам код виджета? Есть ли примеры?

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к вопросу.
С примерами кода все вроде понятно - где должен размещаться код? Например такого виджета - <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-js --> VK.callMethod('showAppWidgetPreviewBox', 'text', 'return { "title": "Цитата", "text": "Текст цитаты" };'); <!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите в итоге вы разобрались как подступиться к виджета? У меня такой же вопрос и никак не могу найти ответа